# How can I get German language in Evolution for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, evolution, language-support

In Ubuntu 16.04, Evolution comes only with English language on a German installation. How can I install or configure the German language pack for Evolution.

Answer (score 1):

Evolution is a Gnome program. So if you are using Evolution in a Gnome-foreign distro (e.g. Kubuntu), it is likely that the needed language pack for Gnome programs is not installed. (In my case, the document viewer *Evince* also didn’t have an interface in my language, since it is also a Gnome program.)

Thus, you need to install the above mentioned language pack. You can do this e.g. via the terminal by typing (for your “German case”)

```
sudo apt install language-pack-gnome-de
```

If someone wants a different language to be supported than German, then he/she/it has, of course, to change the letters after the last hyphen (e.g. to “it” for Italian).

If you are not sure what exactly the ending for your language is – or for any other reason – you can also install the package via a graphical package-management program like *Synaptic*. There, just search for “language-pack-gnome”, choose the package you need, and apply the changes (install it).

You have to re-open the program for the changes to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the spell checker language I think you need to install the dictionary using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install aspell-de
```

As for the interface language it seems there might be a bug with it at least this is reported for the RC not sure if it carried over into the final release:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/1572661

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to venbea (juan-gamez) and it works for all languages

This works fine for me:

1. Download Evolution evolution_3.18.5.2.orig.tar.xz from [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/evolution)
2. Extract translation `{LANG}.po` for your language from `po` directory in archive
3. Convert `.po` file to `.mo`:

   ```
   msgfmt -cv -o /path/to/evolution-3.18.mo /path/to/{LANG}.po
   ```
4. Copy `evolution-3.18.mo` to `/usr/share/locale-langpack/{LANG}/LC_MESSAGES/evolution-3.18.mo`
5. Restart Evolution, enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have a later version of evolution (3.20 for example) you can do the same:
Copy your `evolution-3.18.mo` to

```
/usr/share/locale-langpack/{LANG}/LC_MESSAGES/evolution-3.20.mo
```

Or use the source of a more recent one, one that is not provided by Launchpad.
In my case it worked!

This really is a bug. It seems that it has been resolved for Ubuntu 16.10. Check it out!